# Send Arrow key input to child process in java

Tags: java, arrow-keys, child-process

I want to run a child process in my java program to create automation.
I do not have the source code of the child process.

There are some functionality requires pressing the arrow keys in the child process.

I can send ASCII characters into the child process through the child process's STDIN, but how can I send arrow keys to the child process?

Comment: Is this a question on threads, or are you asking how to implement code to detect an arrow key press?

Comment: I doubt you can encode an arrow key into an ASCII character: arrow key is detected and managed by the command line editor, it's NOT a character that can be sent to as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `java.awt.Robot` (`keyPress`/`keyRelease`). This allows you to send keyboard events, mouse movements and mouse clicks to your OS (among other things).

I suspect sending keyboard events to a specific process (rather than just the OS) is beyond what Java can natively do, though C/C++/C# can probably do something like that.